# Error message: Impossible to create ACCDE, MDE or ADE

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Upon trying to create an execution-only front-end database file in *.accde format, i receive the error message "Impossible to create accde, mde, or ade.  After doing a bit of research i am informed that this message happens when the dimensions of the database are too big.  Looking at my database which is only 10KB with about 40+ linked tables linking to a back end database of 45KB, I am confused as to why I am not allowed to perform this action.

Answer (score 5):

This error is common when there are errors compiling the database.  If you open the database and go into the VBA window are you able to compile the database without a problem (debug menu -> compile)?  If you run into errors compiling the database this way, fix these errors and then once you can successfully compile the file this way then try creating the ACCDE file again.